# TensorFlow: Android classifier app crashes after replacing the frozen graph and labels file?

Tags: android, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

I am following the tutorial from this guide: http://nilhcem.com/android/custom-tensorflow-classifier

and it works perfectly fine.

However, when I tried to change the files to my own use, through using a model I have trained on my own, my app keeps on crashing on the phone without even seeing the camera screen. I thought it would be as simple as replacing the frozen graph pb file and labels file, and then editing the corresponding files and values in the `ClassifierActivity.java`. But it might not be the case.

These are the files that I have changed:

https://github.com/Nilhcem/tensorflow-classifier-android/compare/master...kwotsin:master

Are there any more files that I should be changing? Also, I have performed my quantization operations (which include the strip_unused operation suggested in the `ClassifierActivity.java` file) using the `graph_transform` tool built through bazel, which works perfectly fine on my laptop:

```
/home/kwotsin/tensorflow-android/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph \
--in_graph=./frozen_flowers_final.pb \
--out_graph=./quantized_flowers_final.pb \
--inputs='Placeholder_only' \
--outputs='InceptionResnetV2/Logits/Predictions' \
--transforms='
  add_default_attributes
  strip_unused_nodes(type=float, shape="1,299,299,3")
  remove_nodes(op=Identity, op=CheckNumerics)
  fold_constants(ignore_errors=true)
  fold_batch_norms
  fold_old_batch_norms
  quantize_weights
  quantize_nodes
  strip_unused_nodes
  sort_by_execution_order'
```

Comment: Could you post the error message and/or stacktrace? It's hard to know what could be wrong without. A possible reason might be the pb file size. I know protobuf has a default limit of ~64MB without specifying otherwise

Comment: @MichaelJohnston thanks for your reply! I wasn't able to post the error log due to some driver issue I believe. I have opened up an issue on GitHub recently: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9958. I think the size could be a very valid source of problem. I once tried the Inception V3 frozen model which is around 50+MB compared to the one I tried above (200+MB), without any quantization, the inception V3 one works but the latter fails. Is there a place where you could identify the default limit of 64MB?